# Core Data ensuring data uniqueness

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I've been working with Magical record and Core Data for a while, but still I can't figure out how to ensure object uniqueness.

Assume I have a function:

```
- (void) foo {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        // find if model with x = myValue exists
        MyModel *model = [MyModel MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"x = %@", myValue] inContext:localContext];

        // if there is no model - create it!                          
        if (!model) {   
            model = [MyModel MR_createInContext:localContext];
            model.x = myValue;
            // etc...
        }
    }];
}
```

Everything goes fine until `foo` is called twice (or 3, 4...etc times). Now `localContext` doesn't know about `localContext` in other thread and uniqueness checks passes. As a result after context merge I have 2 (3,4...etc) instances with given value (instead of 1).

How can I ensure only 1 object with given value exits?

**PS**. `—validateValue:forKey:error:` won't help, as it called **BEFORE** context merge (during saving object).

Answer (score 1):

I guess one approach would be to check before merging and alter or delete the duplicate values. You can do this by listening to the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and making the changes before calling `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`.

Comment: I guess you mean make changes between `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` has only context, which is going to be saved. How should I check uniqueness?

Comment: @NikitaTook `WillSave` is probably better, thank you. But the second item is not a notification but a context method.

Comment: @user2786037 It would be the notification for the parent context. All the dupes you want to correct should already be there.

Comment: @Mundi so you mean, I just need to find all duplicates (like `[MyModel MR_findFirstWithPredicate....`) and remove dupes?

Comment: Not sure about MR... but yes, in principal this is the approach. BTW, the other suggestions focus around *deferring* changes to the database to avoid parallel modifications. That could also be a good strategy in principle.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesnt work after a few loops is that the saveWithBlock method is dispatching queues under the covers for you. Because of this, each local context is a fresh new context. Each localContext is unaware of the contents in any of the others created by your loop. This means the findFirst method will return nothing every time and create a new, but duplicate copy of the model object. The way to fix this is to either,

- do all the looping inside the saveWithBlock method
- create your own context and use that for all your data saves in the loop

The idea is to use the same context for all your operations so you can look up data in the context. And in some cases that data will be your newly created and unsaved data.

Comment: I understand where problem comes from, but I can't make only 1 call. For example, if `foo` is an update function (it syncs data from server) it should be called in different situations (for eg push received and application becomes active), but sometimes both situations occurs simultaneously